# SyntaxError when loading a gltf-file via Three.js in React

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf

i'm trying to implement a 3D-Model into a website. When i tried it with a 3D-Model from a website, everything worked fine, but when i try it with my own model i get this console error: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

I programm in react and use three.js to implement the model as a gltf file.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        //Camera fixieren
        camera.position.set(0,12,20);

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        //automatische Fensteranpassung
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        })
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
        this.mount.appendChild( renderer.domElement );



        var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
        scene.add(light);

        var hlight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
        light.position.set(50,50,50);
        scene.add(hlight);

        var controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);


        function frameArea(sizeToFitOnScreen, boxSize, boxCenter, camera) {
            const halfSizeToFitOnScreen = sizeToFitOnScreen * 0.5;
            const halfFovY = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(camera.fov * .5);
            const distance = halfSizeToFitOnScreen / Math.tan(halfFovY);
            // compute a unit vector that points in the direction the camera is now
            // in the xz plane from the center of the box
            const direction = (new THREE.Vector3())
                .subVectors(camera.position, boxCenter)
                .multiply(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1))
                .normalize();

            // move the camera to a position distance units way from the center
            // in whatever direction the camera was from the center already
            camera.position.copy(direction.multiplyScalar(distance).add(boxCenter));

            // pick some near and far values for the frustum that
            // will contain the box.
            camera.near = boxSize / 100;
            camera.far = boxSize * 100;

            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            // point the camera to look at the center of the box
            camera.lookAt(boxCenter.x, boxCenter.y, boxCenter.z);
        }


        //GLTFLoader
        const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
        gltfLoader.load('prototype/public/test.gltf', (gltf) => {
            const root = gltf.scene;
            scene.add(root);

            // compute the box that contains all the stuff
            // from root and below
            const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(root);

            const boxSize = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
            const boxCenter = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

            // set the camera to frame the box
            frameArea(boxSize * 0.5, boxSize, boxCenter, camera);

            // update the Trackball controls to handle the new size
            controls.maxDistance = boxSize * 10;
            controls.target.copy(boxCenter);
            controls.update();
        });





        //Objektloader der net funzt -- leere Seite wird angezeigt
        /*
        loader.load('public/test.obj', function ( obj ){

            var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj);
            var center = new THREE.Vector3();
            box.getCenter(center);
            obj.position.sub(center);

            scene.add(obj);
        })*/


        //Objektloader der net funzt -- leere Seite wird angezeigt
        /*var mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.load("/public/TechnicLEGO_CAR_1.mtl", function(materials){

            materials.preload();

            var objLoader = new OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);

            objLoader.load("/public/TechnicLEGO_CAR_1.obj", function(mesh){
                const ab = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);
                const center = ab.getCenter( new THREE.Vector3());

                mesh.position.x += (mesh.position.x - center.x);
                mesh.position.y += (mesh.position.y - center.y);
                mesh.position.z += (mesh.position.z - center.z);

                scene.add(mesh);


            });
        });*/


        //Würfel
        /*
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        //var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff00ff } );
        var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( cube );*/


        var animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            //cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
            //cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        };
        animate();
    }


    //muss so bleiben, da rendern sonst nix wird
    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={ref => (this.mount = ref)} />
        )
    }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is the gltf i want to load: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mZhyYRBmN8FVac9d3c2T1dN1TpUXPM5Q?usp=sharing

As you may see, i also tried it with .obj-Files, but this wont work either.

Hope smb can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file loads actually fine in the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/). So this issue is most likely not a problem of `GLTFLoader` but of your web server. The error message

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

usually pops up if the `glTF` manifest file is not served as JSON. I suggest you use the developer tools of your browser to ensure a proper HTTP response when requesting the `glTF` asset from your backend.

Comment: I´m not that good in webprogramming, so how should i do this? and what is a proper HTTP response?

Comment: Maybe it's best if you invest some time in getting more familiar with the browser's dev tools. This will allow you to investigate such issues by yourself. It might also help to read the following related topic at the [three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/json-or-gltf-loader-for-three-js-in-react/3898/7?u=mugen87).

Comment: thank you, but as i said, i´m a hard noob in webdevelopment an this link isn´t helping me. If tried loading a file from an online repository and it worked, but why doesn´t my local files work?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and it looks like parcel doesn't copy the static files to dist folder. you can install [parcel-plugin-static-files-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy) and declare static files as guided in README of that package in this link [parcel-plugin-static-files-copy](https://github.com/elwin013/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy). Then the file would load successfully